Google sheets API v4 - Getting 429 [ Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota) ] during spreadsheet creation
I am trying to create a google sheet using java springboot. Even though my request quota hasn't exceeded, i'm getting the 429 Too many requests exception.
Error image : (https://i.sstatic.net/m1axt0Ds.png)
This is my code :

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.Spreadsheet;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.SpreadsheetProperties;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SheetsQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
    
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
    private static final String GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "/google-sheets-client-secret.json";
    
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = SheetsQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }
    public static void getData() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        final String spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
        final String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
        Sheets service =
                new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                        .build();
        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No data found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Name, Major");
            for (List row : values) {
                // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(4));
            }
        }
    }
    public static String createSpreadsheet(String title) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                JSON_FACTORY,
                getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName("Sheets samples")
                .build();

        Spreadsheet spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet()
                .setProperties(new SpreadsheetProperties()
                        .setTitle(title));
        spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().create(spreadsheet)
                .setFields("spreadsheetId")
                .execute();
        System.out.println("Spreadsheet ID: " + spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetId());

        return spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetId();
    }
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

        getData();
        createSpreadsheet("hi");
    }
}

This is the cloud console request metrics  and the quota and limits image for reference.
Here, we can see that there have only been 8 createSpreadsheet requests and 9 get requests.
Another thing to make note of is that all the 9 getValues requests were successful but all the 8 createSpreadsheet requests failed with this error.
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 429 Too Many Requests
{
  "code": 429,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
      "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
  "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}


I cannot explain the 429, but my method to creating a new spreadsheet is to use the Google Drive API and copy a spreadsheet (from a template).  In this case it is notable that you needs to have Contributor (add & edit) permissions on the target folder.  I wonder if the 429 is a misleading error from a permissions limitation.  If you are really stuck - try this method of copying a spreadsheet.

I get an error like this and it doesn't give it all the time. I stated as a prompt that it is a translation application, and while some translations are good, I get this error in others: Error: 429 resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).
I don't fully understand it, and sometimes it gives the following error: Error: Invalid operation: The response.text quick accessor requires the response to contain a valid Part, but none were returned. Please check the candidate.safety_ratings to determine if the response was blocked.
